# Subset Dataframe for even split in column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have the data frame below "bus_rev".  I would like to subset the dataframe so that I have an even number of records where good_reviews==True and good_reviews==False.  Can anyone suggest a slick way to do this?

```
Sample Data:

print(bus_rev[1:3])

                  user_id             business_id  stars_x  \
1  CxDOIDnH8gp9KXzpBHJYXw  XSiqtcVEsP6dLOL7ZA9OxA        4   
2  CxDOIDnH8gp9KXzpBHJYXw  v95ot_TNwTk1iJ5n56dR0g        3   

               address                                         attributes  \
1     522 Yonge Street  {u'BusinessParking': {u'garage': False, u'stre...   
2  1661 Denison Street  {u'BusinessParking': {u'garage': False, u'stre...   

                        categories     city  \
1   [Restaurants, Ramen, Japanese]  Toronto   
2  [Chinese, Seafood, Restaurants]  Markham   

                                               hours  is_open   latitude  \
1  {u'Monday': u'11:00-22:00', u'Tuesday': u'11:0...        1  43.663689   
2                                                 {}        0  43.834295   

   longitude                            name   neighborhood postal_code  \
1 -79.384200                     Kenzo Ramen  Downtown Core     M4Y 1X9   
2 -79.305282  Vince Seafood Restaurant & BBQ       Milliken     L3R 6E4   

   review_count  stars_y state good_reviews  
1            76      3.5    ON         True  
2            23      3.5    ON        False  


Code:

bus_rev['good_reviews'].value_counts()

Output:

False    482
True     168
Name: good_reviews, dtype: int64
```

Comment: So do you want to have the same number of Trues and Falses in the subset? 168 in your code

Comment: @EvanNowak  Thank you for the quick reply.  Yes 168 True and 168 False would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a DataFrame with equal values, you could use:

```
bus_revs_false = bus_revs[bus_revs['good_reviews'] == False]
bus_revs_false = bus_revs_false.iloc(:168,:)
bus_revs_true = bus_revs[bus_revs['good_reviews'] == True]

bus_revs_new = bus_revs_true.append(bus_revs_false)
```

In this case, bus_revs_new will be your new DataFrame with an equal number of Trues and Falses.

Answer (score 1):

To get the same number of Trues and Falses, you can do this:

```
good_reviews_true = bus_rev[bus_rev['good_reviews'] == True]
good_reviews_false = bus_rev[bus_rev['good_reviews'] == False]

bus_rev_subset = pd.concat([good_reviews_true.head(len(good_reviews_false)), good_reviews_false.head(len(good_reviews_true))])
```

Comment: Thank you that was perfect!